# SQL Server : "require open and available connection"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm just learning databases to store a (large amount) of user entry data.

I have the following code, which checks a record and chooses whether to update or create new

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sc1 = @"select count(*) from job1 where report = @report";

    SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand(sc1, connection);
    check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", jname);

    // check if the report number already exists, if not make a new table otherwise insert
    int test = (int)check.ExecuteScalar();

    if (test > 0)
    {
        jobCardExistingTable(connection);
        digCardExistingTable(connection);
        //insert into existing table code                        
    }
```

If I use either `jobCardExistingTable` or `digCardExisting` table, they work fine. If I use both, I get the error

> require open and available connection

I assume that the first `ExecuteNonQuery` (which are contained in the `jobCard` and `digCard` methods) is doing something with the connection - can I keep this one open, or do I have to open a new one each time I call a method? Maybe I'm doing this all wrong anyways...each method is calling a new table in the database, should I be calling them all at once?

Edit: part of the issue is jobCardTable (digCardTable is identical, just a different query)

```
public void jobCardNewTable(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        string sc3 = "";
        sc3 = @"INSERT INTO job1 (" + pv.jobstring + ") VALUES (" + pv.jobparam + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sc3, connection);
        queryParams(cmd, 0);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Edit: solved - realised that using{} disposes the connection. Took all the `using{}` out of the methods, and used a single `using{}` to encompass all the method calls and it works

Comment: what is happening inside `jobCardExistingTable`?

Comment: Can you post code from the jobCardExistingTable and digCardExistingTable ?

Comment: edited, thanks for asking, i realise one issue at least now

Comment: "using{} closes the thread". it's not related with thread. `using` disposes connection resources which need to be open and available for making queries.

Comment: thanks again!  it's good to learn better terminology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `using (connection)` if you are using same connection in other part of code. `using` dispose connection and make unavailable for further connection.

So, your jobCardNewTable method implementation should be without using statement :

```
public void jobCardNewTable(SqlConnection connection)
{
        string sc3 = "";
        sc3 = @"INSERT INTO job1 (" + pv.jobstring + ") VALUES (" + pv.jobparam + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sc3, connection);
        queryParams(cmd, 0);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

I would recommend to create new connection whenever you need it and dispose it.

Comment: thanks, i figured it out now.  sometimes just posting it here and waiting for the downvotes gets me thinking about things differently.  i'll leave the question up and edit for answer

Comment: Great, you figured it out. Sorry for knowing about downvote :( . using statement is only culprit which is disposing your connection